# Contact.LastModifiedById.getDescribe().isCreateable() returns true

Tags: schema

How is it possible that the following code can return true

```
Contact.LastModifiedById.getDescribe().isCreateable()
```

It was my impression that the LastModifiedBy field was never createable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my dev org this apex:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.LastModifiedById.isCreateable()
```

Evaluates to true. There is a black tab option that salesforce support can enable that does allow audit fields like LastModifiedById to be creatable (but not editable). I strongly suspect this was enabled in your org when you checked this.

Comment: You are correct. I confirmed with Salesforce support. Thanks for the response